# Accessing data points in different columns

Tags: r

I have a data set in R that looks like the following:

```
004041  FLASHLIGHT  SUREFIRE    GX2 - TACTICAL  UNK     B-3                     SAT 
004044  FLASHLIGHT  SUREFIRE    G2X TACTICAL    NONE    D-3       1/11/17       SAT 
004045  FLASHLIGHT  SUREFIRE    GX2 - TACTICAL  UNK     D-3                     SAT 
004045  TACTICAL LIGHT  SUNFIRE 4045                    D-3       1/17/18       SAT 2_3VOLT BATTERIES
004048  FLASHLIGHT  SUREFIRE    G2X TACTICAL    NONE    D-3       1/11/17       SAT
```

I want to create a loop or a function that takes an input barcode number and outputs the tool based on columns instead of writing a separate line for every barcode number, but I am having problems. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include what you tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: I tried to format your table as well as I could but I really can't make sense of the 4th line, you  give us the output of `dput(data)`